# How to apply avg function on top of select query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select (SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE_emplogin) as newinfo, USER_ID from emp;
```

Based on the result of the above query I want to take the average on `newinfo` column

I am very much new to SQL I don't understand what to do next

We are oracle db.

Comment: You already have and answer to your question, here is some extra information https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_avg.asp

Answer (score 3):

If it is average per `user_id`, then apply `avg` to date difference and include `group by` clause (which contains all non-aggregated columns):

```
Select avg(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE_emplogin) as newinfo, 
       USER_ID 
from emp
group by user_id
```